# prove that polynomials can only take $0$ value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $f, g, h$ be polynomials of real coefficients such that

$$f^2(x) = x g^2(x) + x h^2(x).$$

Prove that $f=g=h=0$.

Tried so far:

Set $x$ to be any negative number then $f^2=-(g^2+h^2)$ times a positive number, this can only hold if $f=g=h=0$.

Or $x=0$, $f=g=h=0$.

But what about positive $x$? There should be some non-zero real $f,g$ or $h$ right? How to show only $0$ is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: So $f(x)=g(x)=h(x)=0$ for all $x<0$. Can you imagine that there is a polynomial that is $0$ for all $x<0$ but can take non-zero values for $x\geq 0$?

Comment: You can also think like this: a polynomial of degree $n$ is uniquely determined by $n+1$ conditions (since there are $n+1$ free variables in an arbitrary polynomial of degree $n$). So pick any arbitrary $N$ negative numbers, where $N \gg \max\big( \operatorname{deg} f, \operatorname{deg} g, \operatorname{deg} h\big)$ and derive $N$ many conditions for the polynomial, then argue that the $0$ polynomial is the only one to satisfy all the $N$ conditions at once.

Answer (score 3):

$f,g$ and $h$ have infinitely many zeros. Since they are polynomials thyy have to be identically $0$.

A non-zero polynomial can have only finite number of zeros.

Comment: If $g,h$ are not both identically $0$ then deg$(xg^2+xh^2)=1+2\max($deg $(g$),deg($h$)) is odd. But deg$(f^2$) is even.